# Checking if setOnItemClickListener is clicked or not

Tags: java, android

I am making a dictionary app. I have an AutoCompleteTextView and large list of strings. When I set ArrayAdapter to AutoCompleteTextView without shrinking it, it freezes. That's why I decided to set Adapter with TextWatcher. Text on textView changes, textView adapter changes. But when i try to select selected item with onitemClickListener it returns indexoutofboundsException, because textWatcher works before onclickListener and adapter changes. **Is there way to check if item is clicked inside TextWatcher? Thanks for your help**

```
final AutoCompleteTextView textView =  (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() != 0){
                    db.openDataBase();
                     wl = db.getWordList(s.toString());
                    ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, wl.getWordList());
                    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }


        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) != null);
                    Log.i("Debug",parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+"");
                }


        });
```

Here's the error
`05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370): Process: com.alynurly.maralsozluk, PID: 10370
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 4
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:764)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at com.alynurly.maralsozluk.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:92)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
05-30 10:30:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(10370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: or is there any other way to set that adapter without freezing the app? Help me

Comment: adapter changes mean ? Post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I learned that it's possible to check if dropdownitem is clicked by using `autoCompleteTextView.isPerformingOperation()`. So now my new code looks like

```
    @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  //doesn't work if list is clicked
            if(s.length() != 0 && !textView.isPerformingCompletion()){
                db.openDataBase();
                 wl = db.getWordList(s.toString());
                ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, wl.getWordList());
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```